# Populating a form from onblur function. Javascript: JSON.parse returns undefined, although stringify returns values

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is my code:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetCustomerData(string CustomerName)
{
    ClientBusinessLayer clientBusinessLayer = new ClientBusinessLayer();
    var clientId = clientBusinessLayer.GetClientId(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    List<CustomerWithPlans> customersWithPlans                                              clientBusinessLayer.GetCustomersWithPlans(clientId).ToList();

    //Searching records from list using LINQ query
    var Customer = (from N in customersWithPlans
                    where N.Customer.FullName.Equals(CustomerName)
                    select new { N.Customer });
    return Json(Customer, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#Customer_FullName").blur(function () {
            alert("test: " + document.getElementById('Customer_FullName').value);
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Client/GetCustomerData",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'CustomerName': document.getElementById("Customer_FullName").value }),
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (jsondata) {
                    var data = JSON.stringify(jsondata, null, 2);
                    alert("Hello? " + data);
                    alert(jsondata[0].firstname);
                    alert(jsondata.firstname);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("An error has occured!!!");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

If anyone could help me figure out how to get these values to the form, that would be helpful.

Comment: This is the JSON string that is being returned from the method:                     [
  {
    "Customer": {
      "Id": "99602e3c-4070-4434-8646-53abd1fdcf0f",
      "CustomerNumber": 1,
      "FirstName": "Peter",
      "LastName": "Smith",
      "FullName": "Peter Smith",
      "PhoneNumber": "245-456-2345",
      "Email": "peter121@gmail.com",
      "DateOfBirth": "/Date(-62135575200000)/"
    }
  }
]

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to call alert(data[0]['Customer']['FirstName'])